# Simple php if else loop help needed

Tags: php, function

I have a function like this

```
function cp_module_ranks_getRank($uid){
        return cp_module_ranks_pointsToRank(cp_getPoints($uid));
    }
```

It returns the member rank based on points i set.
For example my settings has

1. 250 Points = Bronze
2. 1000 Points = Silver
3. 2500 Points = Gold
4. 10000 Points = Diamond
5. 25000 Points = Platinum

So if a user has 11234 points then that function return value as **Diamond**

Now i would like to set a variable based on this rank.

`$affdays` is the variable

I mean like this

```
If user rank is Bronze $affdays = 30
If user rank is Silver $affdays = 60
If user rank is Gold $affdays = 90
If user rank is Diamond $affdays = 180
If user rank is Platinum $affdays = 360
Default $affdays = 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you use array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a switch statement:

```
$user_rank = cp_module_ranks_getRank($id);

switch($user_rank) {
    case 'Bronze':
      $affdays = 30;
      break;
    case 'Silver':
      $affdays = 60;
      break;
    case 'Gold':
      $affdays = 90;
      break;
    case 'Diamond':
      $affdays = 180;
      break;
    case 'Platinum':
      $affdays = 360;
      break;
    default:
      $affdays = 10;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks.. But my main problem is that i have no idea how to bring that function `cp_module_ranks_getRank($uid)` inside switch statement.   Do i have to assign your `$user_rank` variable in that function?. If yes how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want. Do you want the `cp_module_ranks_getRank()` function to return that `$affdays` value?

Comment: No.. cp_module_ranks_getRank() returns rank value like Bronze which is correct. But you used a new variable `$user_rank`. I'm a php noob. Thats why i asked this question. But now your new variable confusing me more.. I mean from where you passing the values?. Your code has no connection with my cp_module_ranks_getRank() function.

Comment: Yep thats what i'm talking about. Thanks. I'll accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about just creating an array and looking up the corresponding example?

```
$rank = 'Bronze';
$rank_days = array(
  'Bronze' => 30,
  'Silver' => 60
  // etc
);

if (array_key_exists($rank, $rank_days)) {
  $affdays = $rank_days[$rank]; // 30
} else {
  $affdays = 10;
}
```

Comment: +1 this is much better than multiple ifs or a switch statement

Comment: Hi can you tell me how to assign that function to a variable? Do i have to use like this? `$rank = cp_module_ranks_getRank($uid);` and what about the default affdays value?

Comment: That looks ok. I'm just assigning the ranks as the keys of an array and the number of days as the corresponding value; why not test if no corresponding key exists in the array using `array_key_exists()` and assign a default value if needed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the switch statement

```
switch ($user_rank) {
   case "bronze":
      //code
   break;
   case "silver":
      //code
   break;
   default:
      $affdays = 10;
   break;
   //and so on
}
```

it's like an If statement with multiple "elseif's" and it works much faster

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick:

```
    if (cp_module_ranks_getRank($user) === 'Bronze') {
        $affdays = 30;
    } else if (cp_module_ranks_getRank($user) === 'Silver') {
        $affdays = 60;
    } else if (cp_module_ranks_getRank($user) === 'Gold') {

    ...

    } else {
        $affdays = 10;
    }
```

EDIT: The switch statement answer is far better than this one